# Construction of Steiner Porism with concentric circles

Tags: geometry, circles, geometric-construction

I tried to construct Steiner chain in geogebra with 2 concentric circles. I used the radius 2 for big circle and 0.5 for iside circle. So, radius of steiner circles is 0.75. After construction i get as result that 2 circles of my chain aren't tangent. I don't really understand a link between circles radius'. I would like to understand why it doesn't work. Here is an image.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_chain#Annular_case_and_feasibility_criterion) gives a feasibility criterion for a Steiner chain of $n$ circles to be supported between two concentric circles of radii $R$ and $r$:
$$\frac{1+\sin\pi/n}{1-\sin\pi/n}=\frac Rr$$
The parameters you have chosen do not satisfy this relation.

By solving the above equation for $n$, we can determine for given $R$ and $r$ whether there is *any* Steiner chain between the circles:
$$r(1+\sin\pi/n)=R(1-\sin\pi/n)$$
$$(R+r)\sin\pi/n=R-r$$
$$\sin\frac\pi n=\frac{R-r}{R+r}$$
The criterion here is that $n$ must be an integer at least $3$, or at least a rational number $\frac pq$ corresponding to a chain with $p$ circles that loops $q$ times before closing. In particular, if $R$ and $r$ are rational, then by Niven's theorem $n=6$ and $\frac{R-r}{R+r}=\frac12$, implying $R=3r$. But in the diagram in the question $R=2$ and $r=\frac12$, which does not satisfy $R=3r$, so no Steiner chain of any number of circles can exist between these two circles.

---

If we want to have a Steiner chain of $n=5$ circles with the outer concentric circle having radius $R=2$, the first feasibility criterion tells us that the inner concentric circle's radius $r$ must be
$$\frac{2(1-\sin\pi/5)}{1+\sin\pi/5}=22-8\sqrt5-4\sqrt{50-22\sqrt5}=0.519232367\dots$$
[image]

Comment: Thank you! @Parcly Taxel

Comment: @Daniil I added a picture of the correct arrangement.